# Leaflet highlight GeoJSON points within the other highlighted GeoJSON layer

Tags: leaflet, javascript

I would like to have all the points highlighted within the other highlighted GeoJSON polygon.

[image]

Next, I would like to have them displayed in the panel next to or at least in the console (for now).

The problem is, that code I provided doesn't work. I can't see these points anywhere.

```
var ptsWithin = turf.within(placesLayer.toGeoJSON(), total.toGeoJSON());

map.on('draw:created', function (e) {
  placesLayer.clearLayers();
  layer = e.layer;
  placesLayer.addLayer(layer);
  GetSelection(placesLayer);
});

function GetSelection(layer) {

  var shape2 = placesLayer.toGeoJSON() //All facilities
  var ptsWithin = turf.within(total, layer.toGeoJSON());

  alert('Found ' + ptsWithin.features.length + ' features');
  alert("results " + JSON.stringify(ptsWithin));
};
```

which I've picked up from here:

[Leaflet and Turf.js Points within poly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36019221/leaflet-and-turf-js-points-within-poly)

I also tried another approach:

```
var eclplaces = total.toGeoJSON().geometry.coordinates
placesLayer.eachLayer(function (layer) {
  if (turf.booleanContains(eclplaces, layer.toGeoJSON().geometry.coordinates)) {
    selPts.push(layer.feature);
  }
}
```

but with no effect at all.

The same as this code:

[Determine if a point reside inside a leaflet polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790344/determine-if-a-point-reside-inside-a-leaflet-polygon/31813714#31813714)

And the other options, which I found are here:

https://github.com/hayeswise/Leaflet.PointInPolygon
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31790344/determine-if-a-point-reside-inside-a-leaflet-polygon/31813714#31813714

The worst thing is, that console says nothing in these 2 cases.

Is there any way to highlight and list the points, which are located inside the highlighted polygon?

My full code is here:

http://01.mlearnweb.online/